# Valuation ring and integral closure

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, valuation-theory

Let $A$ be a one-dimension local noetherian domain and suppose that we know that $K=\text{Frac}(A)$ is a complete discrete valuation field (valuations for me are surjective). Let's denote with $\mathcal O_K$ the valuation ring of $K$.

In general $\mathcal O_K\neq A$ and I suppose that $\mathcal O_K\supseteq A$ . Is $\mathcal O_K$ the integral closure of $A$ in $K$?

Comment: I don't get it: $K$ has only one discrete valuation?

Comment: If we assume that $K$ is complete, then yes. I forgot to say it, you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral closure of a noetherian domain is the intersection of all the DVRs of its field of fractions, so the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: I can't find an on-line proof of the mentioned result, but one can adapt the one given in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/115747/121097). See also [here](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/ComAlg/ComAlg3.pdf), page 4.